# Calculate the number of characters printed by the println statement

Tags: java, printf

The `printf()` statement in C returns the number of characters it prints.

I want to calculate the number of characters printed by the `System.out.println()` statement. Is there any way to calculate it?

Comment: Did you consult the documentation before asking this question?

Comment: But there are ways to calculate it. That's a valid question!

Comment: I'll edit for cleanup.

Comment: Just count the number of characters in the string that you tell it to print

Answer (score 3):

Look at [the Javadoc for `PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (the class of `System.out`). All of the regular `print` methods return `void`.

If you really want to know the number of characters printed, you'll need to format the string (`String#format`, the equivalent of `sprintf`), handling EOL, and then look at the length.

Answer (score 0):

Put what you are printing into a string first, then get the length of it.